# AdMob - download your own app

Tags: admob

I've created an app (K12 Helper) for K12 students on Google play. This app is free and has AdMob ads of course.

I wrote this one for my kids (and now is available for others to use) and I want them to continue to use it.

My question is can my kids download my app so they can get latest version automatically via Google play? Will that violate AdMob policy? I can't email AdMob because there is support email address :(

Thanks folks.

Comment: Why should downloading your own app violate Admob policy? You may want to add your device id as test-device id though. So that you just see fake ads instead of real ones.

Comment: Ok. I'm new to AdMob, I'll see if I can add the device as test device. Don't know how to do that yet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use this method to add test device id to your AdRequest: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder.html#addTestDevice%28java.lang.String%29